# PHP project access forbidden

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn how to use PHP to send email, and the advice I've been getting has been frustrating.  It's like wanting to learn how to drive stick, but being told how to machine parts to build a transmission.  My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Contact Blackjack Trainer</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/blackjack.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        function spamcheck($field)
        {
            // Sanitize e-mail address
            $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            // Validate e-mail address
            if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    ?>
    <h1>Blackjack Trainer Contact</h1>
    <?php
        // display form if user has not clicked submit
        if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Contact Details</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="from">Name: <em>(required)</em></label>
            <input name="from" id="from" type="test" size="80" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
            <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" size="80" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <p>For defect reporting, please state dealer's hand, player's hand, options, and expected and actual outcomes.</p>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Comments, Suggestions or Defect Reporting</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="message">Message: <em>(required)</em></label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="75" rows="20"></textarea>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <?php 
        }
        else
        // the user has submitted the form
        {
            echo "so far so good";
            // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
            if (isset($_POST["from"]))
            {
                // Check if "from" email address is valid
                $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST["from"]);
                if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
                {
                    echo "Invalid input";
                }
                else
                {
                    $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
                    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
                    $message = $_POST["message"];
                    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
                    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
                    // send mail
                    mail("normhines@hotmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
                    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

However, when I click on Submit, I get "403 Forbidden:  You don't have permission to access /blackjack/< on this server."

How do I get permission to access my own project?  Do I need to install a mail server?  This is just my development platform; I'm not actually hosting my website just yet.

Comment: Your `<form>` tag is malformed. `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>` is missing the closing quote around the action and the closing `>`.

Comment: that's a webserver and/or filesystem problem. you php code isn't even being executed since the location it's in isn't permitted.

Comment: working local or FTP? windows/linux ?

Comment: I'm working local on windows 8.1.

Comment: Well check your file/directory permissions and check your .htaccess if you have one.

Comment: I corrected my malformed <form> tag, and Firefox put an extra "> on my web page.

Answer (score 0):

and try to set chmod 777 in FTP

http://magazynt3.pl/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/tworzymy_strone_z_blogiem-1c.png

Comment: I don't understand.  I'm not using FileZilla.  How do I do this on a Windows 8.1 platform.